# Is there a way to conduct the Anderson Darling test in Python using a custom distribution?

Tags: python, scipy.stats

I'm using the scipy.stats.anderson Anderson-Darling test for some data I have, but I'd like to compare it to a uniform distribution that is relevant to my data, rather than the preset options given by scipy like normal, exponential, etc. The distribution I want to compare it to is really simple, literally just the array:

```
xtest = np.linspace(0, 180, len(x), endpoint=True)
```

where x is my data. Does anyone know if there's a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The function in scipy does not currently support the uniform distribution.  Looking at the code though (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.1/scipy/stats/morestats.py#L1783)

```
    if dist == 'norm':
        ...
        critical = around(_Avals_norm / (1.0 + 4.0/N - 25.0/N/N), 3)
    elif dist == 'expon':
        ...
        critical = around(_Avals_expon / (1.0 + 0.6/N), 3)
    ...
    return AndersonResult(A2, critical, sig)
```

it has logic to calculate the `critical` values for each distribution it supports.

If you're able to calculate the `critical` values for the uniform distribution, you can calculate `AndersonResult` yourself.

Comment: I don't know enough about stats, but this seems like a useful reference too https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35e.htm